# BlueImp's Gallery - Different gallery for different set of images

Tags: jquery, image, modal-dialog, gallery, blueimp

i am using [BlueImp Gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/blob/master/README.md#description).

As title says, imagine facebook image post, when user click on a post's image, i want to show only all the images belong to that post. I don't know how to implement this.

**First and foremost**

I have refer to doc, there is a pure js script like this

```
document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
        link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
        options = {index: link, event: event},
        links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
    blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
};
```

the script works when we have html like this

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="images/banana.jpg" title="Banana">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/banana.jpg" alt="Banana">
    </a>
    <a href="images/apple.jpg" title="Apple">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/apple.jpg" alt="Apple">
    </a>
    <a href="images/orange.jpg" title="Orange">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/orange.jpg" alt="Orange">
    </a>
</div>
```

because of getElementById('links') which wraps the anchor tag

**My problem is**

I have html like this (this is actually twitter bootstrap thumbnail)

```
<div id="post1">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="/test1.jpg" class="thumbnail" target="_blank">
            <img src="test1.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a href="/test2.jpg" class="thumbnail" target="_blank">
            <img src="test2.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

i want to detect when use click on the `<a>` then show all the images belong to this post.

Currently:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.thumbnail', function () {
    var link = $(this);
    blueimp.Gallery(link);
});
```

Let's say user click on `<a href="test2.jpg">`. This function display only test.jpg. I want to display test2.jpg and able to slide to left to test1.jpg

any idea how to achive that? I have been scratching my head T_T

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Container ids and link grouping**

If the **data-gallery** attribute value is a valid id string (e.g. "#blueimp-gallery"), it is used as container option.
Setting **data-gallery** to a non-empty string also allows to group links into different sets of Gallery images:

```
<div id="fruits">
    <a href="images/banana.jpg" title="Banana" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-fruits">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/banana.jpg" alt="Banana">
    </a>
    <a href="images/apple.jpg" title="Apple" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-fruits">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/apple.jpg" alt="Apple">
    </a>
</div>
<div id="vegetables">
    <a href="images/tomato.jpg" title="Tomato" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-vegetables">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/tomato.jpg" alt="Tomato">
    </a>
    <a href="images/onion.jpg" title="Onion" data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery-vegetables">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/onion.jpg" alt="Onion">
    </a>
</div>
```

This will open the links with the **data-gallery** attribute **#blueimp-gallery-fruits** in the Gallery widget with the id **blueimp-gallery-fruits**, and the links with the **data-gallery** attribute **#blueimp-gallery-vegetables** in the Gallery widget with the id **blueimp-gallery-vegetables**.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solutions

there is jquery feature for this problem. Use of data-gallery

have a look at the link

https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#container-ids-and-link-grouping

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818995/bootstrap-image-gallery-html-between-list-of-links-to-image-files